# Authenticate Google-Cloud-Storage in Python using Workload Identity Federation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, openid-connect

Is it possible to use the OIDC method of Google's Workload Identity Federation to authenticate my Python Application's Google Cloud Storage package.

I want to do something like this:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) + "/keys/credentials.json"
from google.cloud import storage

import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
target_audience = "https://pubsub.googleapis.com"

obtained_id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, target_audience)

storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=obtained_id_token)
```

This gives the following error:

`ValueError: This library only supports credentials from google-auth-library-python. See https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for help on authentication with this library.`

Comment: 1) Cloud Storage requires an OAuth Access Token and not an Identity Token. 2) Your code is attempting to create a credentials class using one library and then using that variable in an incompatible library method. 3) Your question mentions Workload Identity Federation but I do not see that in your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your clarification comment. I want to use Workload Identity Federation to avoid the need of working with and passing around sensitive json files. Can I use WIF to authenticate with these Google SDKs?

Comment: These two articles where very helpful to dig deeper: 
https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials-php/
https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Automatic](https://github.com/salrashid123/gcpcompat-oidc#automatic) on Sal's [Exchange Generic OIDC Credentials for GCP Credentials](https://github.com/salrashid123/gcpcompat-oidc) repo.

IIUC this gets your from federated credentials to Google Application Default Credentials (see below) that you can use with **any** Google SDK.

To @john-hanley's comment, you're using the auth library incorrectly.

See [google.auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.html) and specifically (after `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json`) you can just:

```py
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer, I am trying to working with a key.json file. For security I would prefer not to handle and pass around service account json file. I that possible with currently?

Answer (score 2):

This does not solve the Workload Identity Federation part of the question, but does make the question code work correctly:

```
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
target_audience = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/"

# Create ID token credentials.
credentials = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token_credentials(target_audience, request=request)

# Refresh the credential to obtain an ID token.
credentials.refresh(request)

id_token = credentials.token
id_token_expiry = credentials.expiry

storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(settings.GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_NAME)
```

Still need to see if its possible to authenticate without needing the Credentials json file in the repo.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can't _directly_ use an OIDC token (no matter who its issued by) to access a GCP resource like a bucket. If you have any arbitrary OIDC token issued by any provider, you're correct that you need workload federation which will exchange that token for one that google understands (i.,e exchange it for an access token). You just need to create a aJSON file that Google SDK clients understand and point to that file that has that 3rd party id_token using the same `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. You're not actually distributing a service account's key.

Comment: @DazWilkin I think I understand this point now, is there a convenient way to retrieve an OIDC token from local environment while developing?

Comment: @Zaffer - this was super helpful for us, as GCP was barking at us at SourceField for generating signed URLs.

Answer (score 1):

can't reply to comments directly but

for reference, here are some of the links describing this more

- federation will exchange your ambient `aws|oidc|azure`  credentials for one that GCP understands  (theres's no svc account key involved) see
  [gcp workload identity federation](https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2021/understanding_workload_identity_federation/)
- google issued oidc (`id_tokens`) are usually used here to access services you deploy on cloud run, etc see
  [google id tokens](https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2019/google_id_token/)
- finally and just for ref, google has very specific way certain services authenticate using a svc account jwt (its not oidc nor oauth but something google specific)...its not at all common but its described here see [jwt access tokens](https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2021/cloud_sdk_missing_manual/jwt_access_token/)

Comment: thank you, this link is also very helpful to understand what's going on: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications

Comment: @sal is the author of the repo that I referenced in my answer. He's very knowledgeable about security and particularly knowledgeable about Google|GCP security.